# Using Ransacker to filter through relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have the following model entities in my rails application:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  has_many :tracks
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end
```

I'm trying to implement a search form within the index view of Album entity which i need to select all albums which artist.name starts with my search parameter. I've got success dealing with direct model searches but this situation, having to verify a parent attribute to select the children elements, it's giving some headaches.

I've read the Ransacker documentation but don't find anything related to that :(

Comment: It sounds like you first need to find all the artists whose name starts with your search parameter, and then select the albums for those artists. This feels like plain vanilla ActiveRecord queries should be usable here. Something like `Artist.where('name LIKE ?', "#{query}%").select(:albums)` might do the trick.

Comment: I've tried that approach with relative sucess in my index method of AlbumsControllers, as follows:
    `id_artist = Artist.where('name LIKE ?', "#{params[:q][:artist_name]}%").select(:id)`
    `@q = Album.where(artist_id: id_artist).order('year').ransack(params[:q])`

But when my view refreshes, i lose the input from the user in the form. The field ARTIST_NAME gets blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this in a general way, I created a file _search.html.slim, containing the "general search logic", allowing both for "simple" searches (without associations), and complex searches (with associations):

```
= search_form_for @search, url: request.original_url do |f|
  = f.condition_fields do |c|
    .field
      = c.attribute_fields do |a|
        - if local_assigns.has_key? :associations
          = a.attribute_select associations: associations
        - else
          = a.attribute_select
      = c.predicate_select compounds: false, only: [:cont, :not_cont, :eq, :lteq, :gteq, :lt, :gt]
      = c.value_fields do |v|
        = v.text_field :value
  .form-actions
    = f.submit 'Search', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

which I use in my index files as

```
= render 'search', associations: [:artist]
```

passing the associations I want to search on, or just as

```
= render 'search'
```

in case of no associations

my controller looks like

```
def index
  @search = @albums.includes(:artist).search(params[:q])
  @albums = @search.result(distinct: true).paginate(per_page: 10, page: params[:page])
  @search.build_condition
end
```

Comment: Everytime i run a search with this piece of code, i get a new search field. i'd like to restrict the fields only to Artist Name, Album Year and Album Title